# DBGridEh сортировка вычисляемого поля

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

Доброе время суток,
Вопрос:
если в *DataSet* есть вычисляемое поле (сделанное в *TIBDataSet* отображаемое *DBGridEh*, сортировка серверная) напирмер "*calc_СOLOR*", и поле-источник в БД "*СOLOR*".
При нажатии на заголовок колонки "*calc_СOLOR*", я корректирую *order by* и подставляю в запрос "*СOLOR*".
Делаю

```
ADataSet.Active := true;
```

После этого в процедуре *ApplySortingForSQLBasedDataSet* модуля "*DbUtilsEh*", всеравно  поставляется "*calc_СOLOR*"? (Потому что в *order by*, он там подставляет именно название с колонки)
Как поступить?

Answer (score 0):

Т.е. не знаю насколько это правильно...
Но для сортировки по вычисляемому полю (сделанное в TIBDataSet отображаемое DBGridEh, сортировка серверная), т.е. когда левой кнопкой мышки нажимаешь на заголовке колонки вычисляемого поля

сначало в запрос конечно подставляю в предложение order by поле "COLOR":

```
 if AColumn.FieldName = 'calc_COLOR' then
      AColumn.FieldName := 'COLOR';
ADataSet.SelectSQL.Clear;
    ADataSet.SelectSQL.Add(L_SQL1);
    ADataSet.SelectSQL.Add('order by '+ AColumn.FieldName+' ');
    ADataSet.SelectSQL.Add(L_SQL2);
   ADataSet.Active := true;
```

происходит сортировка (в том числе работа процедуры "*ApplySortingForSQLBasedDataSet*" в "*DbUtilsEh.pas*"), которую я прямо вызываю с события "*DBGridEh.SortMarkingChanged*".

```
...

ApplySortingForSQLBasedDataSet(TCustomDBGridEh(Sender), DM.ibdsEquipment, true, true, 'SelectSQL');
  for LInd := 0 to dbgrehEquipment.Columns.Count-1 do
    if DBGrid.Columns[LInd].FieldName = 'COLOR' then
    begin
      DBGrid.Columns[LInd].FieldName := 'calc_COLOR';
      break;
    end;
```

- я ставлю все на свои места

**Это работает**

P.S.
L_SQL1 и L_SQL2 - части одного запроса, просто у меня запрос сложный и 'order by ' стоит в средине самого запроса